# Spark-SQL - Generating multiple rows based on date interval

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I need to write a query in `Spark-SQL` that generates multiple records from one based on a date interval. Here we're trying to simulated SCD-Type 2. The requirements are:
Here, a row will have 2 date columns (eff_from_dt & eff_end_dt) among other columns. For any existing record, if a change (in the values of any of its columns) comes in the input today, the new record needs to be inserted with the new eff_from_dt value; and the existing record needs to be end-dated by updating the eff_end_dt with (new-date -1) value. Now, records need to be generated for every month that exists between the updated record's eff_from_dt and eff_to_dt.

```
Date Dim:
--------

currdt | first_day_of_mth | last_day_of_mth  
-------------------------------------------  
2019-01-15 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-31  
2019-01-16 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-31  
.......
2019-07-25 | 2019-07-01 | 2019-07-31
```

Table Prdct on Day 1:

```
-------------------- --- 
prod_id | price | eff_from_dt | eff_end_dt
------------------------------------------
123 | 30.99 | 2019-02-26 | Null
```

Now imagine a new record comes in for the same Prdct id (123) with a new price (55.99) and new eff_frm_dt (2019-07-16). So now the new row should be inserted and the eff_end_dt column of the existing record needs to be updated with the (eff_frm_dt value of the new record - 1 day). Now create new records (from the existing record) for every month that appears between the eff_frm_dt & the eff_end_dt of the existing record.

Assume new record (for today) given below:

```
prod_id | price | eff_from_dt | eff_end_dt
------------------------------------------
123 | 55.99 | 2019-07-16 | Null 

Target expected:
-----------------

prod_id | price | eff_from_dt | eff_end_dt
------------------------------------------
123 | 30.99 | 2019-02-26 | 2019-07-15  <<--- existing record updated with (eff_frm_dt of new record - 1 )
123 | 30.99 | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-31  <<--- record generated from existing row for March 2019
123 | 30.99 | 2019-04-01 | 2019-04-30  <<--- record generated from existing row April 2019
123 | 30.99 | 2019-05-01 | 2019-05-31  <<--- record generated from existing row May 2019
123 | 30.99 | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-30  <<--- record generated from existing row  June 2019
123 | 55.99 | 2019-02-26 | Null        <<--- Today's new record inserted with new eff_frm_dt
```

In the above example, 4 historical rows are created for each month that lies between the eff_frm_dt and eff_end_dt of the existing row. Also, note that the new (today's) record is also inserted at the bottom with a Null in the eff_end_dt signifying itself as the valid record.